# Is there a full overview about what topic goes on which Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am wondering where to put a certain question (Its about how a certain camcorder shows the computer in what mode its set when plugged in, ie. create dvd or copy files). I have no idea where to put it though.

In general I think it could be very useful for everyone if there was some easy to find overview

Comment: In your case the suitable place would be http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's described [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology).First you have to select tabs like Technology,Science etc...Then you can see list of sites in that category.Clicking a site icon will show you the description.